# c++, how to write several simple vectors to a binary file in one shot

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, vector, binaryfiles

I have very simple but huge vectors:

```
struct Vectors //of the same types and the same sizes
{
    vector<int> A;
    vector<int> B;
    vector<int> C;
    vector<int> D;
    vector<int> E;
    vector<int> F;
}
```

and want to write them to a binary file in one shot.

So far I successfully wrote and read a single vector to a binary file with the help of: `file.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&A[0]), sizeof(A));`, `file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&A[0]), sizeof(binaryfile));`

I did the same thing for these 6 vectors one after another, but when I try to read the binary file, there is an error: `vector subscript out of range`

Could the issue be with the automatic padding? And how to overcome it?
Is it possible to write and then read the whole struct of vectors in one shot? So that it is readily available after I memory mmap the binary file?
By the way, I do not insist on using vectors, I could use arrays or whatever data type is better for my case...

Comment: Your shared code is not enough to find the issue

Comment: You're not getting the correct size for what you want to write or read.  Running a quick test before I post the right sizes.

Comment: how are you reading from file?

Comment: preview: The main problem you need to deal with is getting the size of the data chunk.  And you don't know that, so there's no possible way to just read it in from a binary file.  You're going to want to write the size of each vector in the data file's header, so that when you read, you read the size then you read in that much data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick to reading and writing the whole data section of a vector is getting the size of the data block right before you write it, and then getting the size of the data block right BEFORE you read it.But of course, you don't know the size when you read it, so the size needs to be in the file also. That allows you to allocate that much space for your vector, then read that much data.

Here is one possible implementation. I took shortcuts. Your file header should probably have an identifier you can check so you know that you are reading a file that claims to follow your layout correctly. You really, really need to check to see if the file open and reads/writes work. And I didn't write a test for my operator==(), which I used to test the load/save pair (although I did inspect the values in the debugger once).

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>

struct Vectors {
    std::vector<int> A, B, C, D, E, F;
    bool save(const char * filename);
    bool load(const char * filename);
    bool operator == (const Vectors &rhs);
};

void initialize_dummy_ints(std::vector<int> &v, int size){
    v.resize(size);
    for (int n = 0; n < size; ++n)
        v[n] = n + 1;
}

bool Vectors::save(const char * filename){
    std::ofstream out(filename, std::ios::binary);
    int a=A.size(), b=B.size(), c=C.size(), d=D.size(), e=E.size(), f=F.size();
    out.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&a), sizeof(a));
    out.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&b), sizeof(b));
    out.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&c), sizeof(c));
    out.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&d), sizeof(d));
    out.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&e), sizeof(e));
    out.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&f), sizeof(f));

    out.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&A[0]), sizeof(int)*A.size());
    out.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&B[0]), sizeof(int)*B.size());
    out.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&C[0]), sizeof(int)*C.size());
    out.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&D[0]), sizeof(int)*D.size());
    out.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&E[0]), sizeof(int)*E.size());
    out.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&F[0]), sizeof(int)*F.size());

    // always check to see if the file opened, and if writes succeeded.  
    // I am being lazy here so I can focus on the actual question
    return true;
}

bool Vectors::load(const char *filename){
    std::ifstream in(filename, std::ios::binary);
    int a, b, c, d, e, f;
    in.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&a), sizeof(a));
    in.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&b), sizeof(b));
    in.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&c), sizeof(c));
    in.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&d), sizeof(d));
    in.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&e), sizeof(e));
    in.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&f), sizeof(f));
    A.resize(a); B.resize(b); C.resize(c); D.resize(d); E.resize(e); F.resize(f);

    in.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&A[0]), sizeof(int)*A.size());
    in.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&B[0]), sizeof(int)*B.size());
    in.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&C[0]), sizeof(int)*C.size());
    in.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&D[0]), sizeof(int)*D.size());
    in.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&E[0]), sizeof(int)*E.size());
    in.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&F[0]), sizeof(int)*F.size());

    // always check to see if the file opened, and if writes succeeded.  
    // I am being lazy here so I can focus on the actual question
    return true;
}

bool matches(const std::vector<int> &l, const std::vector<int> &r){
    if (l.size() != r.size())
        return false;
    for (size_t x = 0; x < l.size(); ++x)
        if (l[x] != r[x])
            return false;
    return true;
}

bool Vectors::operator==(const Vectors &rhs){
    return matches(A, rhs.A) && matches(B, rhs.B) && matches(C, rhs.C) && matches(D, rhs.D) && matches(E, rhs.E) && matches(F, rhs.F);
}

int main()
{
    // setup
    Vectors starting_values;
    initialize_dummy_ints(starting_values.A, 10);
    initialize_dummy_ints(starting_values.B, 12);
    initialize_dummy_ints(starting_values.C, 14);
    initialize_dummy_ints(starting_values.D, 10);
    initialize_dummy_ints(starting_values.E, 5);
    initialize_dummy_ints(starting_values.F, 2);

    // write to file
    starting_values.save("data.bin");

    // read back in to memory
    Vectors loaded_values;
    loaded_values.load("data.bin");

    // compare
    if (loaded_values == starting_values)
        std::cout << "success";
    else
        std::cout << "failure";

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

1. You can't simply write out a list of vectors in a single command. Although vectors guarantee that they store their data in contiguous storage space, the data of different vectors will not be contiguous.
2. If you write out the vector in the way you're doing, it is impossible to correctly read it back in, because yo have no idea how many elements the vector had.

---

Given *one* vector, the correct way to write it out and read it in is like this:

```
void writeVector(ostream& file, const vector<int>& A) {
    size_t count = A.size();
    file.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&size), sizeof(size));
    file.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(A.data()), sizeof(A[0]) * count);
}

void readVector(istream& file, vector<int>& A) {
    size_t size = 0;
    file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(*size), sizeof(size));
    A.resize(size); // Make sure the vector has space for what you're about to read in!
    file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(A.data()), sizeof(A[0]) * count);
}
```

I can't think of any way to write out all the vectors in one shot like you want. I suspect it's impossible. It might help a little to use a `vector<vector<int>>` though instead of your `struct Vectors`, as then you can simply run code like the above in a loop:

```
void writeVectors(ostream& file, const vector<vector<int>>& stuff) {
    size_t count = stuff.size();
    file.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&size), sizeof(size));
    for(const vector<int>& v : stuff) {
        writeVector(file, v);
    }
}

void readVectors(istream& file, vector<vector<int>>& stuff) {
    size_t count = 0;
    file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(*size), sizeof(size));
    A.resize(size); // Make sure the vector has space for what you're about to read in!
    for(const vector<int>& v : stuff) {
        readVector(file, v);
    }
}
```

---

Now, if what you want is something that you can easily write out in one shot, then you have to choose something statically sized. Basically, that means you need to use arrays. If you have a struct like this:

```
struct Vectors {
    int A[50];
    int B[50];
    int C[50];
    // ... etc ...
};
```

Then the following read/write commands will work:

```
file.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&A), sizeof(A));
file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&A), sizeof(A));
```

I don't think it's likely there will be padding, but it's not guaranteed.

The above would probably also work if `Vectors` were defined like this:

```
#include <array>

struct Vectors {
    array<int,50> A;
    array<int,50> B;
    array<int,50> C;
    // ... etc ...
};
```

Both ways require you to set a hard upper limit on the size of each array, and if you want them to *seem* dynamically sized, you'll also need to arrange for some particular value to be used as a marker that an element does not exist (one way would be to `#include <limit>` and then have `const int EMPTY = numeric_limits<int>::min();`).

Comment: point, since it's basically the same as my answer.  I assumed the vectors were variable length precisely because he used std::vector instead of a built-in array or std::array.  I use some fixed structures like that (mostly for the file header), and there are ways to specify the padding in the newer standards, as well as some vendor specific ones in current compilers.

Comment: I mentioned the use of arrays because he mentioned he was not attached to vectors.

Comment: Oh bummer, I missed that. If the vectors are always fixed size, then builtin arrays would be best, and he can write the whole structure at once.  If they are not fixed size, then it will be better to write the size, then write that amount of data.  (He did say they were big arrays).  Also I prefer one structure for the file header, and the header would contain all the sizes.  But that may be just me.

Comment: thanks everybody for help! I really seem to have messed up with vector sizes. my vectors are time series data (integers posix time, value1, value2, etc.) of the same size like I mentioned in the comment to struct. I also am not attached to any data type, just wanted to properly write data to binary file and then have it readily available in the same format

Comment: You could also consider using a two-dimensional array, if all your `A`, `B`, `C`, etc are the same size and there are a fixed number of them.

Answer (score 1):

YOur sizeof() is absolutely wrong

for vector of type T (int in your case) as a size you should put `v.size()*sizeof(T)`

something like

```
file.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&A[0]), A.size()*sizeof(A[0]));
```

UPDATE

and if you're using C++11, then you could access underlying storage directly as `A.data()`, so

```
file.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(A.data()), A.size()*sizeof(A[0]));
```

Comment: @KennyOstrom what's wrong with `read` size? It is set to some  `sizeof(binaryfile)` which is hard to interpret but might be about right size

Comment: sizeof(std::ifstream) gets the sizeof an instance of a class that reads files.  It's not associated with any particular file, and it is not the size of the file.  Even if it were, you wouldn't know how much of it went in A.

Comment: @KennyOstrom I don't see sizeof(std::ifstream) in the question. Did I miss something? There is strange expression sizeof(binaryfile), but without defining what `binaryfile` is it is unclear whether it is wrong or not

Answer (score 1):

> I want to write them to a binary file in one shot.

You cannot do such thing.
In order to use a single function to write all the vectors in bulk, all the data allocated in the vectors must be continuous (You can't guarantee it). You can save the vectors one by one, which is probably the best and easiest solution.

Note that:

> file.write(reinterpret_cast(&A[0]), sizeof(A));

is wrong. `sizeof(A)` is actually the size of the vector on the *stack*, while `&A[0]` returns the pointer to it's data on the *heap*. 
To get the size of data, use `A.size() * sizeof(A[0])` and to get the pointer to the data use `A.data()`

The error you are getting is while reading, which happens since you do not allocate enough memory on the vector. The vector's size is 0, and the index `0` doesn't exists, so `&A[0]` throws an exception. Using the function `A.data()` would fix that, but still, you'll need to allocate enough memory to be able to fill the vector.

If your code looks like this

```
size_t sizeToRead; // Retrieved from somewhere 
file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(A.data()), sizeToRead);
```

Make sure you call before the line above to:

```
A.resize(sizeToRead);
```

or initiate A with the size, like so:

```
vector<int> A(sizeToRead);
```

Comment: You might want to look at sizeof(file) again, before you put your stamp of approval on that.

Comment: @KennyOstrom I copied it without thinking from the question, you are right. It was later changed to sizeof(binaryfile).

Comment: You have no way of knowing that the vector is "on the stack". Let's not use this misleading terminology.

Comment: The data of _one_ vector is guaranteed to be contiguous, at least.

Comment: @TalShalti `all the data allocated in the vectors must be continuous (You can't guarantee it)` Yes, in c++11 for vector you can. Standard clarified this issue and added direct access to underlying storage. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data

Comment: One vector is guaranteed to be continuous, but multiple vectors aren't.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Vectors are not on the stack. How would you explain sizeof(vector) with better terminology?

Comment: @TalShalti: You said _"`sizeof(A)` is actually the size of the vector on the stack"_, which is complete bullshit as soon as someone does `new std::vector<T>(...)`. Don't use this nonsense terminology.